# What's wrong with this proof about the cardinality of N^N?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor's diagonalisation argument shows that $|N^N| = |R|$ so obviously $|N^N| > |N|$.

- $N^N$ is $N$ times itself, $N$ times. This is the set of $N$-tuples with elements in $N$.
- To prove that $|N^N| = |N|$ we need to find a bijection between $N$ and $N^N$, a function mapping an element of $N^N$ to an element of $N$.
- Elements $x$ of $N^N$ are of the form $x=(a_1, a_2, ..., a_i, ...)$ where the $a_i$s are elements of $N$.
- Consider the function $f(a_1, a_2,...a_i,...) = 2^{a_1}3^{a_2}...{p_i}^{a_i}...$ where $p_i$s are primes.
- This function is surjective because every natural number has a prime factorisation therefore every element in the range ($N$) is the image of at least one element in the domain ($N^N$)
- This function is injective because prime factorisation is unique so no natural number has two different prime factorisations. So $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ only when $x_1=x_2$
- This function is injective and surjective therefore it is a bijection
- This proves that $|N^N| = |N|$
- But this is obviously wrong! What mistake have I made in this proof?

Answer (score 7):

Can a natural number be the product of infinitely many primes?

For example $(1,1,1,\cdots)\mapsto2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots$ doesn't define a natural.

Answer (score 1):

The proof shows that the finite, or eventually zero, sequences are countable.

However if you have a sequence which is infinitely often non-zero then the product of infinitely many prime numbers is not a natural number anymore. Therefore the function is ill-defined.